# ¿como puedo tener un valor por defecto de una variable con select?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-select

Tengo una variable llamada `params[area]` que me trae un valor, por ejemplo *414*, pero siempre me muestra la prima opción del select, en este caso el valor *0416*, este es el código:

```
<select name="area", "params[area]"   class="mostrar form-control"   style="width: 85px;">
  <optgroup label="Movilnet"><option value="416">0416</option><option value="426">0426</option></optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Movistar"><option value="414">0414</option><option value="424">0424</option></optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Digitel"> <option value="412">0412</option></optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar un método en el *Helper* correspondiente donde compares el valor con el de `params[:area]` con el de la opción:

```
def selected(opt_value, param_value)
  if opt_value == param_value
    'selected="selected"'
  end
end
```

Y en tu vista lo utilzas así:

```
<select name="area" class="mostrar form-control" style="width: 85px;">
  <optgroup label="Movilnet">
    <option value="416" <%= selected("416", params[:area]) %>>0416</option>
    <option value="426" <%= selected("426", params[:area]) %>>0426</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Movistar">
    <option value="414" <%= selected("414", params[:area]) %>>0414</option>
    <option value="424" <%= selected("424", params[:area]) %>>0424</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Digitel">
    <option value="412" <%= selected("412", params[:area]) %>>0412</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Excelente estimado Gerry, funciona perfecto, pero ahora te quiero hacer otra pregunta y con todo respeto, he visto que varias veces me editan mis preguntas y hasta me han calificado negativo, reconozco que me falta redacción, la pregunta es esta. me puedes decir que cosa editaste exactamente, lo que quiero saber es como mejorar mis preguntas porque hay gente, que NO edita, si no que de una califican negativo y no dicen porque.

Comment: @rrg1459 Lo que edito generalmente es el formato de la pregunta para que sea más legible y/o corrección de las etiquetas; en tu pregunta solo edité las etiquetas cambiando la de _ruby_ por _ruby-on-rails_ ya que la pregunta es específica de _Rails_. Tu puedes ver el [historial de ediciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/238475/revisions) en tus publicaciones y, si lo deseas, regresar a una versión anterior. Espero esta información te sirva.